# Android ConstraintSet not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` named rootLayout in my XML.

I would like to have the radiogroup centered and the textview on the top of it

Here is my code :

```
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams groupParam = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                        RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this);
                        group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
                        group.setLayoutParams(groupParam);

                        TextView titleTv = new TextView(this);
                        titleTv.setText(currentQuestion.titleEn);
                        titleTv.setLayoutParams(groupParam);

                        for (int i = 0; i < currentQuestion.listAnswers.size(); i++) {
                            RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(this);
                            btn.setText(currentQuestion.listAnswers.get(i).titleEn);
                            group.addView(btn);
                        }

                        rootLayout.addView(group);
                        rootLayout.addView(titleTv);

                        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
                        constraintSet.clone(rootLayout);

                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);

                        constraintSet.connect(titleTv.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                                group.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 70);
                        constraintSet.connect(titleTv.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
                        constraintSet.connect(titleTv.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);

                        constraintSet.applyTo(rootLayout);
```

But it does not show properly. Is anything wrong in the way I use `ConstraintSet` ?

Edit : Here's what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Just a side note, why don't you use the layout editor? Usually you can see right away what the problem is

Comment: That is a good idea, but I have to add these layouts dynamically (so have to add them through the code, not the XML layout). I guess I'll give it a shot anyway.

Comment: You can use a layout inflater to add dynamic views then you can use xml editor, its much easier I think

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, adding constraintHeight solves the issue

```
                    constraintSet.constrainHeight(titleTv.getId(),
                            ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    constraintSet.constrainWidth(titleTv.getId(),
                            ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score -4):

Alright after trying things around I came across this tutorial :
https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_ConstraintSet_Tutorial

Here's the working code :

```
                        RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this);
                        group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
                        group.setId(R.id.radioGroup);

                        TextView titleTv = new TextView(this);
                        titleTv.setText(currentQuestion.titleEn);
                        titleTv.setId(R.id.titleTv);

                        for (int i = 0; i < currentQuestion.listAnswers.size(); i++) {
                            RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(this);
                            btn.setText(currentQuestion.listAnswers.get(i).titleEn);
                            group.addView(btn);
                        }

                        rootLayout.addView(group);
                        rootLayout.addView(titleTv);

                        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

                        constraintSet.constrainHeight(group.getId(),
                                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        constraintSet.constrainWidth(group.getId(),
                                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);


                        constraintSet.constrainHeight(titleTv.getId(),
                                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        constraintSet.constrainWidth(titleTv.getId(),
                                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);

                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
                        constraintSet.connect(group.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);

                        constraintSet.connect(titleTv.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                                group.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
                        constraintSet.connect(titleTv.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
                        constraintSet.connect(titleTv.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                rootLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);

                        constraintSet.applyTo(rootLayout);
```

Comment: Just pasting code with a link is not a sufficient answer